# How to check if a List<Class> contains a Class while avoiding Sonar rule squid:S2175

Tags: java, sonarqube

I have a list of allowed custom annotations and I'm trying to check whether a specific annotation is allowed by calling the `contains` method on the list.
This works but Sonar complains about rule `squid:S2175`. It says:

> A "List<Class>" cannot contain a "Class"
>
> A couple Collection methods can be called with arguments of an incorrect type, but doing so is pointless and likely the result of using the wrong argument. This rule will raise an issue when the type of the argument to List.contains or List.remove is unrelated to the type used for the list declaration.

How can I fix this?

Here's a minimal example:

```
private boolean testClassContains(){
        final List<Class<? extends Annotation>> annotations = Arrays.asList(MyAnnotation.class,YourAnnotation.class);

        return annotations.contains(YourAnnotation.class);
}
```

Comment: I suggest always using a `Set` instead of `List` when doing a lookup, but this will likely not solve the issue of sonar cube complaining

Comment: The Sonar diagnostic appears to be erroneous, and the diagnostic message does not seem to capture the details that trigger it, since of course it is nonsense that a `List<Class>` cannot contain a `Class`.  I speculate that perhaps the wildcard bound factors in to the issue, so maybe you can work around it by declaring `annotations` as a `List<Class<?>>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) First ensure you are using fresh versions of SOnarQUbe/SonarJava plugin

2) SonarQube is software written by people, so it could have errors. For example, similar case https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sonarqube/qyOOOZORBNs 
 I suggest you file issue in their Jira.

3) Meanwhile, just suppress it. Suppressing is not evil if you have reason to do so